# How do I push a batch script into the background and disown it?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, background-process

I ran the below script to start the WebLogic server. Now if I close the command prompt window, WebLogic would shutdown. Is there a way I can make it go into the background and disown it from the shell just as we do in UNIX?

**cmd.exe >**

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\kent>cd "C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\EPMSystem\bin"

C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\EPMSystem\bin>startWebLogic.cmd
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms256m -Xmx512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Production
.
...
...
...
<Sep 30, 2013 6:21:47 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING>
<Sep 30, 2013 6:21:47 AM EDT> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <Server started in RUNNING mode>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it involves creating a VBS file. Save it anywhere

### Hidden.vbs

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run """" & "C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\EPMSystem\bin\WebLogic.cmd" & """", 0, False
```

Save & Run this anytime, and it will run this batch file hidden from view (not even in the task-bar).  However, the process "cmd.exe" will still exist in task manager, and ending this process will end the file.

At **any** time you want to end all instances of cmd running type the following at command prompt:

```
taskkill /f /im "cmd.exe"
```

And that will allow you to exit it

Mona

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `start` command to execute the program. See: http://ss64.com/nt/start.html

```
Syntax
    START "title" [/Dpath] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

So the command you'd need would be: `start "" startWebLogic.cmd`