# How can I keep the django server still running after close Command Prompt

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django Project. I try to run the server with the command: python manage.py runserver in cmd. However, when I close the cmd, the server also closes too. So is there any way to run a django server and keep it running continuously even if I close the cmd? I'm using Windows. Thanks in advance.

I already tried some solutions like adding a "&" symbol (python manage.py runserver &), but it is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a program continue to run after log out from ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954302/how-to-make-a-program-continue-to-run-after-log-out-from-ssh)

Comment: Hi @FUZIION , The "nohup" command that they mentioned is for  Linux system. I don't know does Windows has the similar command or not.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092339/how-do-i-push-a-batch-script-into-the-background-and-disown-it or this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656147/how-do-i-keep-my-django-server-running-even-after-i-close-my-ssh-session